# Excel formula that adds numbers in cells but ignores the letters

Tags: excel, formula

is there a formula that will ignore letters in cells but sum the numbers? For example, each of these (letter and numbers) are in an individual cell  n7.5  d7.5  n7.5  D11.25  N11.25  e7.5, the formula should add those numbers but ignore the letters.  Please help.

Comment: Are they always first 1 character is letter or in you real data it can more that one letter?

Comment: Yes, the first character in the cell is always a letter followed by numbers.

Comment: Then try my below answer and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If your data always start with single letter (provided sample data) then you can try-

```
=SUM(--MID(A1:A6,2,100))
```

For older versions of excel you have to enter the formula as array entry means enter by `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: It didn’t work, I tried the formula w ‘regular enter’ and also the ‘control+shift+enter’.  Any other suggestion pls?

Comment: It must work. Can you show your data and formula you tried? Also what is your excel version?